# Showing that the first order statistic of pdf $f(x)=2(x-\mu)$ is consistent for $\mu$

Tags: limits, statistics, convergence-divergence, statistical-inference, order-statistics

I am given that $X_i$ are iid for $i=1,\cdots,n$ from pdf $f(x)=2(x-\mu)$ over $(\mu,\mu+1)$, and $0$ elsewhere. I am asked to show that the first order statistic is a consistent estimator for $\mu$.

So far, I have found the pdf of the first order statistic to be given by $$f_1(x)=2n(x-\mu)(1-(x-\mu)^2)^{n-1}$$
After that, I tried to show that $\mathbb E[(X_{(1)}-\mu)^2] \xrightarrow p 0$, since I understand that showing this demonstrates that $X_{(1)}$ is a consistent estimator for $\mu$. However, as part of trying to show this, I try to find $$\mathbb E[X_{(1)}^2] = \int_{\mu}^{\mu+1} t^22n(t-\mu)(1-(t-\mu)^2)^{n-1}dt$$
and I am unable to evaluate this integral.

Am I on the right track? Is there some clearly better way I should be going about this? If not, how do I proceed?

Comment: You don't want to expand it out. You want to leave it in subtracted form, and try to argue that the pdf of $X_1$ is mostly localized near $\mu$ for large $n$. The driving force for this is the asymptotic behavior of $n(1-(x-\mu)^2)^{n-1}$ away from $\mu$, which is exponential decay. The tricky matter is that you have to go far enough away from $\mu$ for the other term in the PDF to not be too small.

Comment: Also, do you need to specifically show convergence in mean square? It is far easier to show convergence in probability.

Comment: @Ian no, I was using convergence in mean square only as a way to demonstrate consistency. I will instead try showing that $X_{(1)}\xrightarrow p \mu$ directly.

Comment: @Ian the suggestion that expanding was the wrong path and that I ought to show convergence in probability directly allowed me to find the solution. As such if you care to write your comments up as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions in the comments, I reasoned as follows.

Let $1>\epsilon>0$.
\begin{align*}
P(|X_{(1)}-\mu|>\epsilon) &= P(X_{(1)}-\mu>\epsilon\\
&=\int_{\epsilon}^1 2nt(1-t^2)^{n-1}dt\\
&<\int_\epsilon^1 2n(1-\epsilon^2)^{n-1}dt\\
&<2n(1-\epsilon^2)^{n-1}\\
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0
\end{align*}